# Read from a socket without knowing the size of the buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I've added a delimiter to the end of all of my messages, so I know when I have reached the end of a message. Once my message exceeds the specified size of the buffer, and I have to read from the socket a second time, weird stuff happens. For example a random '\n' character will appear out of nowhere somewhere random in my message, and this only happens when I have to read from the same socket more than once because the message is larger than the size of the buffer. Is there anything flawed with the code below?

I'm using the Unix socket header file.

```
std::string bufferStr;

// check to see if the delimiter is in the buffer string
while(bufferStr.find(DELIM)==std::string::npos)
        {
            valread = read(sock,buffer,1024);
            bufferStr+=std::string(buffer);
        }
```

Comment: What is the size of `buffer`? Is it `1024`?

Comment: @tadman `1024` bytes

Comment: There is a lot of code not shown, that could potentially be the source of the problem. Do some debugging to narrow down where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of problems here, but most important is you disregard how many bytes were read.

You *must* pay attention to this and use it when constructing the string:

```
std::string(buffer, valread);
```

If you disregard this then you're passing in what's presumed to be a NUL-terminated C string, but instead you just have the raw data, no terminator, and left-over garbage from the last read call.

You should also check that `valread` is > 0 as that could indicate an error while reading. Passing a negative value to the constructor is going to cause problems.